# Why scalac gets confused my SAM type not implementing Function when it overloads 'andThen'?

Tags: scala, single-abstract-method

Tested with 2.13, but I presume it's been like that since 2.12 and I just had not encountered this type of problem before:

```
trait Extractor[-X, +Y] {
    def optional :X => Option[Y] = apply

    def apply(x :X) :Option[Y]

    def andThen[Z](extractor :Extractor[Y, Z]) :Extractor[X, Z] = {
        val first = optional; val second = extractor.optional
        Extractor { x :X => first(x).flatMap(second) }
    }

    def andThen[Z](req :Y => Z) :Extractor[X, Z] = {
        val first = optional
        Extractor { x :X => first(x).map(req) }
   }

   def compose[W](extractor :Extractor[W, X]) :Extractor[W, Y] = extractor andThen this

   def compose[W](req :W => X) :Extractor[W, Y] = Extractor(req andThen optional)

}
```

Scalac has a cryptic complaint about the implementation of the first `compose`:

```
Error:(44, 31) type mismatch;
found   : net.noresttherein.oldsql.morsels.Extractor[X,Y]
required: W => ?
def compose[W](extractor :Extractor[W, X]) :Extractor[W, Y] = extractor andThen this
```

Commenting out the `andThen` variant taking a function solves the issue.
So does changing the code to `extractor.andThen[Y](this)` (explicit type parameter is the key here).
My guess is that somehow my SAM type gets promoted to a function, but I can't guess why would it take precedence over a method. As I provided here two 'solutions', I am looking not as much for workarounds, but to understand what is happening. It's the first time in years I don't understand what's happening and would like to eliminate similar issues in the future.

Comment: SAM-conversion only applies to lambda expressions, and `this` isn't a lambda, so it shouldn't be relevant here. And I can't see any reason for expected type to be `W => ?` and not `X => ?` even if it somehow was triggered. I think this is just a compiler bug. But it's very late here and I am tired so I _could_ be missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly, you are falling afoul of the new rules for [overloading resolution](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution), which are designed to assist type inference.

The question is what is the "expected type" of the arg in `extractor.andThen(this)`.

"The intuition for higher-order function parameter type inference is that all arguments must be of a function-like type."

So removing the `apply` method breaks that condition and lets typing proceed.

The spec adds: "The intent is not to steer overloading resolution."

It should read: "The intent is not to break overloading resolution."

I guess good intentions pave [many roads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_road_to_hell_is_paved_with_good_intentions).

Edit: it works in 2.12 without the amended rules. Under the old system, there is no expected type if the method is overloaded.

Worth adding that it probably qualifies as a regression. For example, they could do a fallback typecheck under the previous rules.

Here is a [ticket](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11907) for it.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know it worked under 2.12 and I was not oblivious to this all the time. I am quite used to things breaking when changing scala versions, but usually it's about in quite convulted examples, mainly with path-dependent types; it was the first such a simple case I've encountered.